# Convert an Array of strings to an array of int in python

Tags: python, arrays, data-conversion

number_of_fails(['1','2','3']) # this is my current array, I want it to be int

coverted_nof = int(number_of_fails) # what I tried to do to convert to an int

output:

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Please show your actual code - you might want to use a list comprehension.

Comment: What kind of error did you faced? And please show your codes?

Comment: `list(map(float, yourlist))`

Comment: `[float(n)] for n in yourlist]`

Comment: Please show your code [_as formatted text in the question_](/help/formatting). This allows people to copy your code into their own execution environments to test it, so they won't have to type it all from scratch. Also, it makes your code searchable so people looking for answers to the same problem can find it in the future. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: the command list(map(float, yourlist)) worked well thank you @d

Answer (score 0):

## initializing list

```
array = ['a1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] 

for i in range(0, len(array)): 
    if array[i].isdigit():
        array[i] = float(array[i])
```

## Printing modified list

```
print ("Modified list is : " + str(array))
```

Modified list is : ['a1', 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]